# SAPUI5 Data Binding on SimpleForm

Tags: data-binding, odata, sapui5, sap-fiori

I am having issues trying to bind data on a simple form. I am using a mock server and have successfully bind data to a list/table

My manifest.json looks like this

```
"mock": {
    "dataSource": "mainService"
}
```

My mockdata(UserDetailsSet.json) looks like this

```
[{
    "ID_PassNum": "cu001",
    "Title": "Mr",
    "Name": "Don",
    "Surname": "Ownery",
    "ResType": "SA",
    "Country": "South Africa"
}]
```

My SimpleForm fields looks like this

```
<Label text="Name" />
<Input value="{mock>/UserDetailsSet/0/Name}" />
<Label text="Surname" />
<Input value="{mock>/UserDetailsSet/0/Surname}"/>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem to be using an `ODataModel`. In ODataModels binding against collections/aggregations is not as easy as it is with a JSONModel. You can't access/bind properties with the `collection/index/property` syntax.

**How ODataModels store data**

If you load an entity set like your `UserDetailSet` the data stored in you ODataModel like look somewhat like this:

```
{
  UserDetailSet('00001'): { ... },
  UserDetailSet('00002'): { ... },
  UserDetailSet('00003'): { ... },
  UserDetailSet('00004'): { ... }
}
```

Whereas '00001' and so forth is the entities key. If you create an aggregation binding on `UserDetailSet` the ODataListBinding will handle translating the above data into a context per item.

**Property Binding on ODataModel**

Your binding would have to look like this:

```
<Label text="Name" />
<Input value="{mock>/UserDetailSet('00001')/Name}" />
<Label text="Surname" />
<Input value="{mock>/UserDetailSet('00001')/Surname}"/>
```

**Dynamic Property Binding on ODataModel**

Or - to be a little more dynamic - bind like this (Note: the bindings are relative now, no leading `/`):

```
<SimpleForm id="MyForm">
  <Label text="Name" />
  <Input value="{mock>Name}" />
  <Label text="Surname" />
  <Input value="{mock>Surname}"/>
</SimpleForm>
```

and dynamically use `bindElement` on the SimpleForm itself:

```
this.getView().byId("MyForm").bindElement({
  path: "/UserDetailSet('"+ sUserID +"')",
  model: "MyOdataModelID",
  // use OData parameters here if needed
  parameters: {
    "expand": "UserAdress"
  },
  // react on binding events here
  events: {
    change: function (oEv) { },
    dataRequested: function (oEv) { },
    dataReceived: function (oEv) {}
  }
});
```

BR
Chris

Comment: Hi

Thanks for your help. Still not working but thanks for an educative response.

Regards

Comment: Hi
Besides what is in initial post I have the following

Manifest
"dataSources": {
   "mainService": {
    "uri": "/here/goes/your/serviceUrl/",
    "type": "OData",
    "settings": {
     "annotations": [],
     "odataVersion": "2.0",
     "localUri": "localService/metadata.xml"

And a List below my form fields which is actually displaying data based on the mock server. I dont have code in the init event of my view controller. I tried your code like this

this.getView().byId("MyForm").bindElement({
  path: "/UserDetailSet('00001')",
  model: "mock" })

Regards

Comment: Is the key of your desired UserDetail entity really '00001'? This was just an example I made. If your key is of type integer this would be "/UserDetailSet(1)" or for a multi-property key, e.g. "/UserDetailSet(ShopID='NY',UserID=1)"

Comment: Thank you for travelling with me.

Answer (score 0):

binding should be like this

```
<Label text="Name" />
<Input value="{mock>Name}" />
<Label text="Surname" />
<Input value="{mock>Surname}"/>
```

if its only one object in the mock. if not working put the controller code where you setting model to the view

Comment: Hi 


Thanks for your help. Tried your binding suggestion but it didnt work. What exactly do you mean by "put the controller code where you setting model to the view". Is this what you mean or how to do it?:
        onInit: function      {  // View Controller
            this.getView.setModel('mock');
            ....

Thank you

Comment: Ok then mock model is having list.. Then change to mock>/0/name

Comment: Thanks. 

Had already tried that and it didnt work.  

Thanks for your help